# Why I cannot add field to a JS object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm programming Node with Sequelize ORM for MySQL. I need to add a new field to the object that Sequelize returns on a query, but it doesn't seems to work.

```
Category.find({
  where: { id: req.params.id }, 
  include: [Item]
}).success(function(category) {
  var items = category.items;
  var ci = category.items.map(function(item) { return item.id; });
  delete category.items; // this works
  category.item_ids = ci; // this doesn't
  // category['item_ids'] = ci; // this doesn't work as well

  res.send({
    category: category,
    items: items
  });
});
```

`Object.isExtensible` returns true on `category` object, but I can't figure out how to actually extend it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
.success(function(category) {
  category = category.toJSON(); // convert to a simple JS object
  ...
  category.item_ids = ci;
  ...
  res.render(...);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, fixed my problem. Although `typeof(category)` was returning `object` and I know is a JSON, still I couldn't add a field to it.

Comment: @Airwavezx `toJSON()` actually returns an object, but a plain JS one and not a Sequelize class instance. If you can't solve your problem, you should consider creating a new question.

Comment: No no! your answer resolved my problem. I was using Mongoose object though.

Comment: @Airwavezx oh yeah, with Mongoose objects there's a similar issue, in that you can't add fields to them (unless you can `.toJSON` or `.toObject` on them).

Answer (score 0):

You can add a computed property:

http://www.sequelizejs.com/documentation#models-expansion

Comment: I need to pass the object as JSON response, don't think that accessors would help in this case.